# Ember acceptance tests fail when running all at once

Tags: ember.js, qunit, acceptance-testing, ember-qunit

I have problems with acceptance tests (ember 0.10.0). The thing is, tests run successfully if I run them one by one (passing test ID in URL), but when I try to run them all at once, they fail cause of some async problems I think (such as trying to click on an element which has not been rendered yet). Has anybody faced that? [Here's](https://gist.github.com/reillyethan/2b68d66a84fad9df79fa) the gist with the example of one of my tests

P.S. I tried to upgrade versions of: qunit, ember-qunit, ember-cli-qunit, but the problem still exists (edited)

UPD 1

Here's the screenshot: https://pp.vk.me/c627830/v627830110/e718/tAwcDMJ0J4g.jpg

UPD 2

I simplified tests as much as I could and now, 50 percent they r passing. I mean, I run all tests and they are marked as done successfully, I run all tests again and they are failed. That blows my mind.

Answer (score 1):

Common reasons for failing are:

1. Some resource that is used by more than one test isn't reset properly between tests. Typical shared resources are:  databases, files, environment settings, locks. This is the most probable cause.
2. Some asynchronous work gets different timing and doesn't complete in a time, and you use a timer instead of more reliable ways to wait for completion.

Comment: 1. Yeah, I thought of that, but I destroy app afterEach test and create it beforeEach, so I think it might be enough to prevent such things

2. I use only async helpers provided by Ember (fillIn, click, visit) and andThen if I need to use some synchronous things in tests. 

P.S. In fact, my tests are very simple I think, I really don't get why I have this problem. Also I can provide a screenshot of error message if it helps (see UPD 1)